# golang: json array that has also methods

Tags: json, go

I have a data structure like this:

```
type (
  parent struct {
    Items []*child
  }
  child struct {
    Field string `json:"field"`
  }
)
```

I also want `parent` to have methods:

```
func (p *parent) example() { }
```

However the json requirement is that parent is just an array:

```
[
  {
    "field": "data"
  }
]
```

I want `parent` to be a simple array, but in order for `parent` to have methods, it cannot be an array type.

Is there a way to solve both problems with one data structure?

(To make matters more complicated, the actual data structure I have to work with has two levels of this: `greatgrandparent` contains `[]grandparent`, and `grandparent` has a `parent` that contains `[]child`. The json structure is externally defined, the arrays have no key names, and I would like methods on each of the four structs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in order for parent to have methods, it cannot be an array type.

It can, it just MUST have a *name* because only named types (or pointers to named types) can implement methods. The following is valid Go code:

```golang
type parent []*child

func (p parent) example() { /* ... */ }
```

*Note that the above `parent` is a slice and not an array. Arrays in Go have static length, you cannot grow them and you cannot shrink them, slices on the other hand have dynamic length and you can resize them at will. Arrays and slices are closely related but not the same.*

---

An alternative would be to have the struct type implement the `json.Unmarshaler`/`json.Marshaler` interfaces:

```golang
type parent struct { Items []*child }

func (p *parent) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &p.Items)
}

func (p parent) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(p.Items)
}
```

The above will produce the required JSON structure.

Comment: Another thing to pay attention to is the use of `*` (or not) in the method definition. e.g., `func (s *parentStruct) example()` versus `func (a parentArray) example()`. This ultimately was my blind spot.

Comment: @jws anytime you have a method that will be modifying the receiver, the method should be declared with a pointer receiver.

Comment: For a non-modifying receiver method, does the pointer save object copy? Or have I been unnecessarily using `*myStruct` almost always for structs?

Comment: @jws whenever the method is invoked a copy of the receiver is created. If the receiver is a pointer then the pointer is copied, which is about 8 bytes, the pointed-to-object is not copied. If the receiver is not a pointer then the object itself is copied, this becomes a copy of about `unsafe.Sizeof(object)` bytes. Copying is fast and even big objects may be easier to memory_manage than pointers, however the object could become so large that a pointer becomes more than warranted.

Comment: Solved cleanly as suggested: a `type` to name the array, and use of indirection in the methods - `func (p *parent) example()` and inside, things like `len(*p)`, instead of `len(p.Items)`. Thanks!